# Place multiple php vars as lat/long in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, php, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

This is what I have... PHP pulls down 10 pairs of lat/long from an API url which I have managed to get working okay but I cannot seem to plot them on a map with multiple markers labelled 1-10.

My php code:

```
<?php
// Loading Domus API
    $url_search = 'http://url/site/go/api/search';
    $xml_search = @simplexml_load_file($url_search) or die ("no file loaded") ;
//Displaying latitude and longutude
$house = json_encode($house);
          }; ?>
```

JavaScript bit:

```
var locations = "<?php foreach($xml_search->property as $house) { echo $lat = $house->address->latitude , $long = $house->address->longitude;}; ?>";

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 10,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.0625,-95.677068),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));
}
```

Which is then needs to be displayed in here

```
<div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px"></div>
```

But I just get a blank page, of course.

Comment: Are you getting any JS errors?  Are you correctly loading in the Google Maps API JS?  How are you calling the JS above; is it all inline, or is it in a function that you're calling; and if so, how?

Comment: No, I am not getting any errors - just a blank page. I don't actually know much about JS.

Comment: well all the javascript above should be in a function.  This should be called on window load, see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#LoadingMap

Comment: well the problem I am having is parsing lat/long from php to javascript...

Comment: How do you know that?  If so, try using `parseFloat(locations[i][1])` etc

Comment: Because I don't think I am doing it right. The php array is like this: http://home.justdima.com/map-view (view the source).

Comment: What does your generated JS look like?

Comment: I've just updated it, so I now get a map http://pastebin.com/TDPTG7bJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've managed to figure it out.

Here is my php code in the head part

```
<?php
// Loading Domus API
$url_search = 'http://url/site/go/api/search';
$xml_search = @simplexml_load_file($url_search) or die ("no file loaded") ;?>
```

Then I have my javascript

```
// Load property ID followed by Lat and Long for each house (total of 10)
var locations = [<?php foreach($xml_search->property as $house) {
        echo '['.$house->id. ',' .$house->address->latitude. ',' .$house->address->longitude.'],';
        } ?>]; 

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 15,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var marker, i;
var markers = new Array();

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map
  });

  markers.push(marker);

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));
}

function AutoCenter() {
  //  Create a new viewpoint bound
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  //  Go through each...
  $.each(markers, function (index, marker) {
  bounds.extend(marker.position);
  });
  //  Fit these bounds to the map
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
AutoCenter();
```

Works beautifully, now just need to set up labelled markers and I am good to go.